# getElementsByClass[index] not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var g = document.getElementById('my_div');
        for (var i = 0, len = g.children.length; i < len; i++)
        {
            (function(i){
                g.children[i].onclick = function(){
                    $('.galao')[i].attr('id','selectedGalao');
                }    
            })(i);
        };
```

So, I'm trying to get a element by his class and index position so I can add an id that I work with. The problem is the browser returns me:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined at HTMLDivElement.g.children.(anonymous function).onclick`

How do I fix it?

**EDIT**

The code is actually like this:

```
var g = document.getElementById('my_div');
            for (var i = 0, len = g.children.length; i < len; i++)
            {
                (function(index){
                    g.children[i].onclick = function(){
                        $('.galao')[index].attr('id','selectedGalao');
                    }    
                })(i);
            };
```

Comment: Show the HTML, we might be able to give you better solution

Comment: `$('.galao').eq(i).attr`

Comment: This might not be your solution, but you should ideally be using `getElementsByClassName` to get the array of elements with the class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way:

```
var g = document.getElementById('my_div');
        for (var i = 0, len = g.children.length; i < len; i++)
        {
            (function(){
                g.children[i].onclick = function(){
                    $($('.galao')[i]).attr('id','selectedGalao');
                }    
            })(i);
        };
```

The elements inside a jquery array, aren't jquery objects, so you need to make them jquery objects too, to use jquery functions on them

Comment: the comma in for loop.  Really?

Comment: i just copied, anyway it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, use it properly, it will optimize your code great deal:

```
$('#my_div').children().click(function() {
  $('.galao').eq(i).addClass('selectedGalao');
})
```

Another advice, use class `selectedGalao`, not `id`, as id must be unique, and if multiple elements can get same `selectedGalao` id, this is not right.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var g = $('#my_div');
for (var i = 0; i < g.children.length; i++) {
    g.children()[i].on('click', function () {
        $('.galao')[i].attr('id','selectedGalao'); 
    });
};
```